# Ubiquity crashes when installing from CD

Tags: installation, 10.10, cd, ubiquity

I didn't want to take any risks so I ordered a CD from Canonical to get Ubuntu. Thing is, another CD was given to me about 2 days before the CD from Canonical got to me, so I installed Ubuntu 10.10 but there was a problem with the login screen (When the Ubuntu logo should be displayed, it wasn't, instead it would just say "Ubuntu 10.10") so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 10.10 with the CD that arrived a few days later.

Whenever it's finishing the installation, the installer (ubiquity) crashes, or sometimes it gets to the part where the boot loader should be installed and for some reason it is unable to install the boot loader (if I choose not to install it, I don't get how to start Ubuntu, since you have to reboot my laptop after the installation is over).

I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.10 from the CD I ordered, since I have no other OS on this laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Often this is due to a problem with the installation CD. To verify the integrity of your copy of the CD:

1. Boot to the CD.
2. When the [image: Accessibility Options] symbol appears, press any key.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the default language, then use the arrow keys to select "Check disk for defects" and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image: Live CD menu]